# 403 Forbiden. CSRF failed - ONLY FOR ONE USER randomly. Works ok after cleaning cash on the computer, but after day or 2 its same error again

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

One mac user randomly gets "CSRF verification failed" error when submiting a form.
When he cleans the cache, its working good for a day or two, and then gets same error again.
Cleaning the cache solves problem. But does not hold for long.

only one user, others are fine. for 3 years was working fine.

Any hints what can be the reason?